# Error after segue to Storyboard Reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I segue from one Storyboard where the View Controller is written in Objective C to another Storyboard where the View Controllers is written in Swift 2 and it goes through fine.

However, when I click fire the next segue in the second Storyboard, I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'record'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

This is the code that calls the next segue in Swift 2

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("record", sender: nil)
```

The initial view in the second Storyboard is embedded in a Navigation Controller as well.

Also worth noting, I tried without the first storyboard and my app going directly to the second storyboard, and it finds the segue fine.

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?

Comment: `ViewController1 embedded in NavigationController?`

Comment: @Rafeek yes it is, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the segue, go to its Attributes inspector and change the Kind from push to Modal. Let the presentation and Transition remain default.

[image]

This will work fine for you.

But if you want the segue of kind 'Push' then the first View controller which is written in Objective-C should be embed in Navigation Controller.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for that yes before you had posted this, I had fixed the problem by changing the segue from a push to modal. But I'll mark your answer as the fix as it was essentially what I had done.